# Safety of IPA and sodium hypochlorite mixture?

Tags: safety

Is the mixture of 97% isopropyl alcohol and 0.5% of sodium hypochlorite safe?
Do they react together and form any compounds ?

Does this mixture present more danger to humans and animals than its ingredients separately ?

Comment: The SDS that I looked at indicated that oxidizing agents are incompatible with isopropyl alcohol.

Comment: As for above if this is meant to be a disinfectant or so, mixing the two would likely reduce the activity of at least one ingredient.